# Oracle Application Express Charts

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm still getting "Invalid chart query" error while trying to make flash chart with APEX. 
My query code:

```
select null, sum(kwota), to_char(data_zakupow,'YY-MM')
from zakupy
group by to_char(data_zakupow,'YY-MM')
```

When i use it as a database query I get:

```
NULL|SUM(KWOTA)|TO_CHAR(DATA_ZAKUPOW,'YY-MM')
-   10  12-11
-   4   12-03
-   63  12-01
```

IDK why I get this error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your fields aliases:

```
select null as link, sum(kwota) as value, to_char(data_zakupow,'YY-MM') as label
from zakupy
group by to_char(data_zakupow,'YY-MM')
```